# Importing parts of luis in json

Tags: json, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I am working on a production app using luis.
I have 2 luis instance containing a preproduction and a production version.
When I develop a new functionnality, I add my intents and uterence in preproduction first.
I found a button for downloading the json of intents and Entities.
Now I would like to import this json or part of it in my production but I can't find it...
Did someone here succeded doing it.

Comment: would you like to completely override the prod version?

Comment: not the best solution for me but can be a workaround

Comment: why not update the version of the LUIS app and then publish it??

Comment: That is what i am trying to do: update by inserting my json from another luis instance

Comment: But what exactly do you mean by "I cant find it" in your original post? Can you please put a step by step approach that you followed??

Answer (score 3):

Go to `Manage` > `Versions` and use `Import version` button:

[image]

Before importing, make sure that you modified your LUIS json to match the following:

- `versionId` should be changed to be the right value you want in your production side
- `name` field must also match the production project name

Then you will have this version imported you will be able to train it, and publish it once you're ready.

Quick reminder: this imported JSON does not contain any changes that you could have made in Production version, it's only like a backup / restore from what you have in Pre-Production

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways you can approach it. If you are importing the model from another app entirely, just go to Manage->Versions and then select Import Version. You cannot import if the versionId (Version Name) if the same as one as you have already (you can rename versionId in the json file if needed).

Alternatively; if the preproduction version is in the same app; just publish to the Production slot. Then, you can clone that to be the next preproduction for further modification and development.

As @Mandar pointed out; it will help if you clarify what you mean by "can't find it".